# Execute login button when enter key is pressed

Tags: java, swing

How can I execute my `loginButton` when the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed? I tried several things but didn't work

```
public void actionlogin(){
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String roosterName = loginUser.getText();
            String roosterPassw = loginPassw.getText();

            if(roosterName.equals("admin") && roosterPassw.equals("admin")) {
                Rooster gotoRooster = new Rooster();
                gotoRooster.setVisible(true);
                dispose();

            } else {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Username/Password");
                loginUser.setText("");
                loginPassw.setText("");
                loginUser.requestFocus();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make any button the default button. The default button will be invoked when the Enter key is pressed.

When you create the button and add it to the frame you use logic like:

```
frame.getRootPane.setDefaultButton( loginButton );
```